# Express $\cos(\tan^{-1}(x))$ in terms of $x$.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Express $\cos(\tan^{-1}(x))$ in terms of $x$.

My Attempt:

Let $\tan^{-1}(x)=A$.

$$x=\tan (A)$$

Then,

$$\cos(\tan^{-1}(x))=\cos (A)$$

Comment: It is already in terms of $x$...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, the ans is $\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1+x^2}}$?

Comment: Draw a right-angled triangle, with one angle A, and two sides 1 and x

Answer (score 4):

Use the relation $$1+\tan^2(A) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(A)}.$$ If you set $A=\tan^{-1}(x)$, you obtain $$1+x^2 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\tan^{-1}(x))},$$ so that $$\cos(\tan^{-1}(x)) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan(A) = x$$
$$\frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)} = x$$
$$\frac{\sin^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)} = x^2$$
$$\frac{1-\cos^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)} = x^2$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(A)}-1 = x^2$$
$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(A)} = x^2+1$$
$$\cos^2(A) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$\cos(A) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$
$$\cos(\arctan(x)) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I always find it helpful to draw a picture. Note that
$$-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \arctan x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

and hence $$\cos(\arctan x) > 0$$